# colour the points in the plane

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Given a finite number of points in the plane, no three of which are collinear, prove that it is possible to colour the points with red and blue so that every half plane that contains at least three points should contain both a red point and a blue point.

It's an old contest problem, I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Look at the vertices of the convex hull. Alternate colors on them. This reduces the problem to when the convex hull is a triangle.

Comment: The case of the triangle argue how you can exclude the two vertices painted in the same color.

Comment: Possible source: https://www.komal.hu/verseny/2002-01/mat.e.shtml (end of the page, problem “A. 281.”).